# Change Boolean Values to 'Yes' or 'No'

Tags: python, oop, boolean

I'm having trouble with converting boolean values into a string 'Yes' or 'No'.

```
class Worker():
  def __init__(self,name,duty):
    self._name = name
    self._duty = duty

  @property
  def name(self):
    return self._name
  @property
  def duty(self):
    return self._duty

  @duty.setter
  def duty(self, duty):
    if duty == True:
        return f'Yes' if self._duty else 'No'

  def __str__(self):
    return f'Name: {self._name} Duty: {self._duty}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w1 = Worker('John', True)
    print(w1)
```

I want the desired ouput to be Name: John Duty: Yes
However, right now im getting Name: John Duty: True

Comment: `@duty.setter` -> `@duty.getter`? maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duty setter is not getting called. I modified the code to work on my machine.

```
class Worker():
  def __init__(self,name,duty):
    self._name = name
    self._duty = duty
    self.duty = duty
    
  @property
  def name(self):
    return self._name

  @property
  def duty(self):
    print("This was never called")
    return self._duty

  @duty.setter
  def duty(self, duty_):
    if duty_:
        self._duty = 'Yes'
    else:
        self._duty = 'No'

    return self._duty

  def __str__(self):
    print(self.duty)
    return f'Name: {self._name} Duty: {self._duty}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w1 = Worker('John', True)
    print(w1)
```

Answer I got was:

```
This was never called
Yes
Name: John Duty: Yes
```